# Nexudus Coworker desks fields have empty array value for the users who have their desks

Tags: slack-api, slack-block-kit, slack-bot

I have integrated Nexudus to Slack bot, and I want to get the desks information of a coworker user from Nexudus.
I can user nexudus coworkers endpoint to get the full information of coworker, and it includes the `Desks` field in the response body.
But the problem is the Desks value is empty array though the user has own desk.

Comment: I am not sure `Desks` field is custom or original field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Desks array in the Coworker entity is only used to associate a new customer with one or more desks, it will not have a value for existing customers.

Desks (FloorPlanDesks) in Nexudus are associated to customers (Coworkers) via contracts (CoworkerContracts).

To figure out what desks a customer is using based on the Id of that customer, you can get the list of contracts (https://developers.nexudus.com/reference/search-coworkercontract) by the Id of the customer. You may also want to filter the list to only include active contracts.

```
GET https://spaces.nexudus.com/api/billing/coworkercontracts?coworkercontract_coworker=:coworkerid&coworkercontract_active=true
```

The response will provide the following keys which will give you a summary of names and ids for the associated desks to those contracts.

```
{
"FloorPlanDeskIds": "1004266268,1004270271,1004270272,1079156153",
"FloorPlanDeskNames": "Office 1,Desk 6,Desk 7,Desk 6",
"FloorPlanDeskAreas": null,
}
```

You can also get the full details of each of the desks associated to a contract or a list of contracts using https://developers.nexudus.com/reference/search-floorplandesk.

```
https://spaces.nexudus.com/api/sys/floorplandesks?floorplandesk_id=[1004266268,1004270271,1004270272,1079156153]
```

Comment: Are you affiliated with Nexudus? Support worker? Owner? Answering from a position of deep knowledge is of course appreciated. Just try to avoid confusion caused by your user name please.

Comment: Nexudus team here 

Comment: Welcome. Let me mention (in a neutral way, I think you are doing fine) https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion just to help you. You might want to proudly state your team status in your profile.

Comment: Is there any endpoint to get statistics information of one coworker? For example, total checked in counts in this year, or top product coworker ordered, etc